# Add key frame every five frames? Autohotkey?

Tags: windows, scripting, workflow, autohotkey, after-effects

I am trying to make an AutoHotKey script to smoothen up my After Effects workflow. The deal is i have to make a keyframe, then go 5 keyframes ahead, this ultimately takes me **9 keypresses** to do! So I tried to cut this down to just 3.

This is my code:

```
^+1::
Send, ^ & ! & + & {F1}

Send, ^ & {Right}
Send, ^ & {Right}
Send, ^ & {Right}
Send, ^ & {Right}
Send, ^ & {Right}

return
```

I want it to press

ctrl+shift+alt+F1 then ctrl+right_arrow 5 times.

What am i missing?

SOLUTION:
So I also asked this question on Reddit, where a user told me that the "Send," command is very literal, so it ended up typing " ^ & {Right}" and " ^ & ! & + & {F1}" in letters, furthermore it was unnecessary to type a & and the spaces between the others, which I also found out using a keyboard tester. So the solution was to type:

```
^+1::
Send ^!+{F1} 

Send ^{Right}
Send ^{Right}
Send ^{Right}
Send ^{Right}
Send ^{Right}

return
```

Comment: I've tried a keyboard tester, and this is what shows up http://prntscr.com/t6z6oa

Comment: You don't explain what exactly is not working -- and I did not understand the prntscrn shot.
Two questions:
Did you set up  "ctrl+shift+alt+F1" manually? THis is not a standard AE key. What keyframe to you try to add? Opacity would be Alt Shift T, Position would be ALT Shift P -- you must have set up a personal one for your combo, right?
Q2: I am not so familiar with AHK but what is the meaning of the comma after the Send command? This is for text. For commands it is not used imho

Comment: So did you ever return here to stackoverflow. Can you update us on this - otherwise this question will not help other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For commands do not use the comma after send (this is for text only)

Answer (score 0):

`SendInput {ctrl DOWN}{Left 5}{CTRL UP}`

This is one method. Rinse and repeat for the other keys, like shift.
Another method is an exclamation point for alt, a cap for ctrl, and a plus for shift.

`SendInput ^!+{left 5}`

According to the post below, I guess adding a comma converts to send raw? But I'm not sure if that's true. I'll test it out later.

You could also make a function, like a loop or whatever. That might be fun. Pass the keys and the number of times to push them as parameters. Coding challenge!